# Dropzone acceptedFiles error

Tags: dropzone.js

Kindly help on filtering image types to upload, I've done some trial and error but can't get this to work. Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

   Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
   var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#mydropzone",{
      url:"upload.php",
      uploadMultiple: true,
      maxFilesize: 2,
      maxFiles : 3,
      acceptedFiles: ".jpg,.jpeg,.png", <-- this won't work
      dictInvalidFileType: "You can't upload files of this type, only png or jpg file",
      autoProcessQueue : true,
      parallelUploads: 3,
      addRemoveLinks: true,
   });
});
```

I've tried:

```
acceptedFiles: "image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/png",
```

but still no uploads in the directory..if I removed the comma in:

```
acceptedFiles: ".jpg,.jpeg,.png"
```

it worked, uploads is showing up on my directory folder but it's accepting all types of uploads..is there some kind of ordering to make this work? anyone help pls?

Answer (score 3):

You can work in init function

```
        var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#designdocumentexcel",
            {
                acceptedFiles : ".xls,.xlsx,.csv",
                init: function(){
                    this.on("error", function(file, errorMessage) {
                        alert("error : " + errorMessage );
                    });

                },
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
$(function(){
    // Dropzone.autoDiscover = false; <-- You don't need it, remove it!
    Dropzone.options.mydropzone = { <!-- string mydropzone is the form id
        url:"upload.php", <-- Put this in form action
        acceptedFiles: "image/jpeg,image/png", <-- jpeg = jpeg/jpg
        // the other options...
    };
});
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score -1):

You have to insert  "/path/to/dropzone.js"
instead of  cdn

and in that file, you can change the config acceptedFiles: null to ..like

acceptedFiles: 'image/*',